# How can I use a CSS transform to vertically-center two overlapping elements?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a relatively-positioned div wrapper, and I want to vertically-align a div inside of it.  Various other Stack answers seem to suggest this is the right way to do this:

```
.vcenter {position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

That works great, but only for a single child element.  I want to have two overlapping child divs, a picture and some text, both vertically-centered within the wrapper div:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="foo vcenter"></div>
  <div class="bar vcenter"></div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work - the transform applies to both children, but the second child is offset vertically by the height of the first child.

I made a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLm3h1o8/1/) that may make this clearer.

Is there a way to get both elements to each center as if they were the only child?

(PS - don't tell me to replace them with a single div containing the text and the image as a background, they need to move independent of each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use position absolute instead of relative:

```
.vcenter {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

[Updated plunkr](http://jsfiddle.net/35bhrbnu/)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.  Evidently I don't really grasp absolute positioning intuitively yet...

Comment: absolute positioned elements don't take up space so you can stack them on top of each other. Relative positioned ones still take up space thats why they were pushing each other out of the way. Your containers should be relative, then position things absolutely inside of that container.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the inner elements to overlap, the best approach is absolute positioning, because it will take the elements out of the normal flow.

Then, to center, you can use the absolute centering technique:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
```

```css
.wrap {height: 100px; width: 200px; border: solid red 1px; position: relative; }
.foocenter {position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 30px; }
.barcenter {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px; }

.foo {height: 60px; width: 140px; background: blue; z-index: -5; opacity: .5; }
.bar {height: 80px; width: 120px; background: yellow; z-index: -6; }

.hcenter.vcenter {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
I want to do get this effect:
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="foo foocenter"></div>
  <div class="bar barcenter"></div>
</div>
<br>
One child:
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="foo vcenter hcenter"></div>
</div>
<br>
Two children:
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="foo vcenter hcenter"></div>
  <div class="bar vcenter hcenter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, there was no need to change the centering technique. Well, I hate the translate one.

Comment: I'm curious as to why?  In this case, that messed up the formatting within one of the child div elements, and the translate method worked fine.

Comment: @DevOfZot I don't like the "move 50% up" techniques because if the element is taller than its wrapper, the upper part will overflow and you won't be able to see it even if you use the scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.  I did some testing and discovered the reason why your solution did not work for me was because one of the child divs I'm using does not have a fixed height.  The fiddle I mocked up to illustrate my problem did, so my example was poor.  My apologies.